# Printing colored string in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to print a string with colored styling into the terminal. I currently have this code:

```cpp
std::cout << "\u001b[1m\u001b[101m My String\u001b[49m\u001b[22m" << std::endl;
```

but this prints out: `?[1m?[101m My String ?[49m?[22m`?

I believe this is a error with the way C++ evaluates the `\u001b` character, as the following Javascript returns the string with the expected styling:

```js
node -p "'\u001b[1m\u001b[101m My String\u001b[49m\u001b[22m'"
```

Comment: Try with `\e` instead of `\u001b`.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis This is just ANSI.

Comment: Tip: [`chalk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk) for Node can help with determining the color strings to use.

Comment: Are you compiling for C++11 or later? Do you have the same problem if you use hex/octal sequences instead of Unicode sequences? `std::cout << "\x1b[1m\x1b[101m My String\x1b[49m\x1b[22m" << std::endl;`  or `std::cout << "\033[1m\033[101m My String\033[49m\033[22m" << std::endl;`

Comment: @tadman note that `\e` is a non-standard extension

Comment: Using `gcc version 7.2.0`. `\e`, `\x1b`  makes no difference still rendering `?`. On further reading I want to render a [vt100 code](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php).

Comment: post one of your comments as the answer, so people can clearly see it.